# Do provinces in Canada have different financial laws/regulations?

Tags: discussion, tagging, country-tags

I saw this question: [Can I take advantage of lower interest rates while I'm stuck in a fixed-rate mortgage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/can-i-take-advantage-of-lower-interest-rates-while-im-stuck-in-a-fixed-rate-mort)

tagged with both "Canada" and "Ontario".

I understand the Canada tag, but Ontario?   Is there a financial difference between Ontario and other provinces?

Pardon my ignorance, I'm just not sure at what locality level should we be tagging questions.

Comment: I think this question should actually be generalized to the last point about how specific a tag should be for locality, e.g. if a question was asked about New York State Sales tax should there be a New-York tag and a United-States tag.

Answer (score 4):

Being in the US I don't know about all Canadian finances, but I do know more than I want to about Canadian Sales tax, and it definitely differs between provinces; HST, no HST, etc.

To answer your question I think a question specific to your province should be tagged with just that province (ie `ontario` but not `canada`).

Comment: LOL.  +1 for "I do know more than I want..." :-)

Comment: You raise a good point.  Your recommendation can also apply to other region specific questions.  I'm sure there are questions specific to certain states and not others in which case a specific tag helps.

Answer (score 1):

There can certainly be differences between provinces on financial regulations.  Taxes certainly differ by province.  And, at the moment, there are multiple provinces each with their own security regulator.

However, I think you're on the right track: in the specific case in question, the province tag is likely unnecessary.  I think mortgage products are regulated federally and the problem and suggested answers are likely province-agnostic.

Comment: This is something the moderators can watch out for and help clean-up.